# Django - how to write test for DRF ImageField

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-tests, django-unittest

I have the following serializer:

```
from rest_framework.serializers import Serializer, ImageField

class MySerializer(Serializer):
    avatar = ImageField()
```

how can I write a unit test for it?
I used the Django TestCase, but it raises an error.

```
from django.test import TestCase

class MySerializerTest(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.data = {}
        ...

    def test_image(self):
        import tempfile
        self.data['avatar'] = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=".jpg").file
        r_data = json.dumps(self.data)
        j_data = json.loads(r_data)
        serializer = MySerializer(data=j_data)
        if not serializer.is_valid():
            import pprint
            pprint.pprint(serializer.errors)
        self.assertEqual(serializer.is_valid(), True)
```

but it raises the following error:

> TypeError: Object of type 'BufferedRandom' is not JSON serializable

What's my mistake? how can I write a test for image field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest to use `SimpleUploadedFile` class from django and create and image using [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) package. See the example below.

```
from PIL import Image

from django.core.files.uploadedfile import SimpleUploadedFile
from django.test import TestCase
from django.utils.six import BytesIO


class MySerializerTest(TestCase):
    ...

    def test_image(self):
        image = BytesIO()
        Image.new('RGB', (100, 100)).save(image, 'JPEG')
        image.seek(0)

        self.data['avatar'] = SimpleUploadedFile('image.jpg', image.getvalue())
        serializer = MySerializer(data=self.data)
        self.assertEqual(serializer.is_valid(), True)
```

Comment: it raises an error again. "TypeError: Object of type 'SimpleUploadedFile' is not JSON serializable"

Comment: Do not serialize it to JSON, why do you need that?

Comment: So, how can i test serializer containing an ImageField? as you see, it's a serializer with an ImageField. I want to write test for it.

Comment: As you can see, it's already written in my example. You don't need to pass a JSON string to Serializer, simple dictionary will be enough to make it work.

Comment: now it raises another error! the error is "'str' object is not serializable". this error is in line "serializer.is_valid()".

Comment: please update your question with the latest version of the code, so I can help you

Comment: thanks. it was my mistake that raised the last error.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you upload a file you would use the `multipart` request format, and the view would convert the image into an `InMemoryUploadedFile` object, and that gets passed into your serializer

So to fix your tests I'd recommend trying:

```
from PIL import Image
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
from django.conf.files.uploadedfile import InMemoryUploadedFile

...

def test_image(self):
    image = Image.new("RGB", (100, 100))
    with NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=".png", mode="w+b") as tmp_file:
        image.save(tmp_file, format="png")
        tmp_file.seek(0)
        byio = BytesIO(temp_file.read())
        inm_file = InMemoryUploadedFile(
            file=byio,
            field_name="avatar",
            name="testImage.png",
            content_type="image/png",
            size=byio.getbuffer().nbytes,
            charset=None,
        )

        self.data['avatar'] = inm_file
        serializer = MySerializer(data=self.data)
        if not serializer.is_valid():
            import pprint
            pprint.pprint(serializer.errors)
        self.assertEqual(serializer.is_valid(), True)
```

What this is doing is:

1. Create an image in memory using PIL.Image
2. Create a NamedTemporaryFile to store the Image data
3. Take the NamedTemporaryFile and read into a InMemoryUploadedFile
4. Pass this InMemoryUploadedFile into the serializer

Comment: it raises an error: "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'InMemoryUploadedFile'"